# onLocationChanged() takes too much time to call

Tags: android, kotlin

In the physical device, it takes too much time to call. But in avd it's run perfectly. I test this code in redmi note 4 and zuk z2 plus. Both device location set on `HIGH_ACCURACY` . I want to fetch the location rapidly. But it takes too much time to execute.

```
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0f,wcLoactionListener)
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0f,wcLoactionListener)
```

But if I removed this line

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0f,wcLoactionListener)
```

then onLocationChanged() not calling.

Here is my location listener

```
class MyListener:LocationListener {



    override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location?) {

        Log.d("Loc","*************************************************** "+ location)
    }

    override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String?, status: Int, extras: Bundle?) {

    }

    override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String?) {

    }


    override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String?) {

    }
}
```

**Mainactivity:-**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val LOCATION_CODE = 212
    private lateinit var locationManager: LocationManager
    private lateinit var cwcLoactionListener:MyListener
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        cwcLoactionListener = MyListener()
        checkLocationPermission()
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun fechLOc(){
        locationManager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0f,cwcLoactionListener)
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,500,0f,cwcLoactionListener)
    }

    private fun checkLocationPermission() {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=23){

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){

                requestPermissions(arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), LOCATION_CODE)
                return
            }
        }
        fechLOc()
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {

        when (requestCode) {
            LOCATION_CODE->{
                if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Accept this permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }else{
                    fechLOc()
                }
            }
            else ->{
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
            }

        }


    }
}
```

manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: Try a reasonable min times, for example 20 second: `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,2000,0f,wcLoactionListener);`

Comment: still not working

Comment: Well, it's GPS. GPS takes time to warm up and lock on.

Comment: Ok. so how uber fetch our location immediately after starting the app?